# Mask One 2D Numpy Array By Argmax Along Axis Of Another Array

Tags: python, numpy, masking

I have a 2D numpy array that I need to take the max of along a specific axis. I then need to later know which indexes were selected for this operation as a mask for another operation which is only done on those same indexes but on another array of the same shape.

Right how I'm doing it by using 2d array indexing, but it's slow and kind of convoluted, particularly the mgrid hack to generate the row indexes. It's just [0,1] for this example but I need the robustness to work with arbitrary shapes.

```
a = np.array([[0,0,5],[0,0,5]])
b = np.array([[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])
columnIndexes = np.argmax(a,axis=1)
rowIndexes = np.mgrid[0:a.shape[0],0:columnIdx.size-1][0].flatten()
b[rowIndexes,columnIndexes] = b[rowIndexes,columnIndexes]+1
```

B should now be array([[1,1,2],[1,1,2]]) since it preformed the operation on b for only the indexes of the max along the columns of a.

Anyone know a better way? Preferably using just boolean masking arrays so that I can port this code to run on a GPU without too much hassle. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest an answer but with slightly different data.

```
c = np.array([[0,1,1],[2,1,0]])  # note that this data has dupes for max in row 1
d = np.array([[0,10,10],[20,10,0]]) # data to be chaged
c_argmax = np.argmax(c,axis=1)[:,np.newaxis]
b_map1 = c_argmax == np.arange(c.shape[1])
# now use the bool map as you described
d[b_map1] += 1
d
[out]
array([[ 0, 11, 10],
       [21, 10,  0]])
```

Note that I created an original with a duplicate of the largest number.  The above works with argmax as you requested but you might have wanted to increment all max values. as in:

```
c_max = np.max(c,axis=1)[:,np.newaxis]
b_map2 = c_max == c
d[b_map2] += 1
d
[out]
array([[ 0, 12, 11],
       [22, 10,  0]])
```